# Setting up a sender mail in Flutter mailer other than gmail

Tags: flutter, dart

May I know how can I setup a mail client other than gmail, in the documentation it says to use smtpServer package but I can't seem to figure it out. I'm using Webmail and want to know how I can set it up.

sendMail() async {

```
String username = 'test@gmail.com';
String password = '*******';

final smtpServer = gmail(username, password);
final message = Message()
  ..from = Address(username)
  ..recipients.add(_email) //User Email
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the steps is to turn on less secure apps on your Google Account:
check this link https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en#zippy=